# Audio webaudio class won't accept source with "C:/" type url

Tags: javascript, express, audio

```
let audio = new Audio("C:/audioFile.mp3")
```

The code above gives me "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" error, it automatically adds the file:/// prefix to the url. It works fine with /folder/audioFile.mp3 type urls (without the windows drive thing), however I cannot access other hard drives on windows that way.

I've used xhtmlrequest with AudioBufferSourceNode before and that worked alright (it's going to be a local electron app that is supposed to have access to the filesystem, so web browser security is not an issue). I cannot use AudioBufferSourceNode because I need to stop, pause, seek and so on.

The web page is loaded from an express server running on localhost, however when using the C:/ style url, the server won't even get a request, it just throws the error in the web browser's console. Putting the same url into the webbrowser directly works, so the url is alright. Tested in several browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't specific to audio.

> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

No matter what you do on the web, you can't add paths this way.  You must use `file:`.

> however I cannot access other hard drives on windows that way

Correct, this is not allowed.  There are a ton of restrictions when using `file:`.

> I've used xhtmlrequest

XHR isn't relevant as there's no HTTP server to make requests of!

> The web page is loaded from an express server running on localhost

Somehow get an actual file reference and use a Blob URL, and you should be fine.  Otherwise, you'll have to proxy the data via your Express server.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I've managed to get it working by swapping ":" for "$" and doing the reverse on the server, works nicely and I can get any file I need now

Comment: @JacklinHeirdom Ok, be careful about ensuring the origin when you proxy those files so that you don't reveal the user's hard drive to others!